# Akka http redirect request to https with FQDN

Tags: redirect, https, akka-http

Using Akka http, how can I redirect any request on http to https and, if necessary, add the full domain to the host name?

I was looking at the Directives.redirect function but it seems to be protocol unaware...

[Edit]: Typo in title, "Akke" -> "Akka".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference, I used `Http().bindAndHandle` and constructed the route as follows:

```
lazy val httpsRedirectRoute: Route = extractUri(redirectHttps)

def redirectHttps(uri: Uri): Route = redirect(toHttps(uri), StatusCodes.PermanentRedirect)

def toHttps(uri: Uri): Uri = uri.copy(scheme = "https")
```